# I want to use data recieved in axios outside axios

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

my code that I am trying

let suggestions

```
suggestions = href.indexOf('/register/company/step-two/internship') > -1) {
    console.log('here')
    cities = axios.get('/get/cities')
        .then((response) => {
            return response.data.cities
            // suggestions.map(city => city.text)
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

this returns a Promise but I want the data

I also tried

```
axios.get('/get/cities')
        .then((response) => {
            suggestions = response.data.cities
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

but no go so any help on this will be appreciated..

Comment: The second one should word correctly for you, what is the error you are facing?

Comment: it returns undefined to me outside

Comment: You can't get the data, they're not there yet. You have to wait for them. Put the code that needs the data in the promise callback.

Comment: how to do that?